# BingMapsDirectionsTask on device with WP 7.8

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I've problem with using BingMapsDirectionsTask on device with Windows Phone 7.8 and set polish language (pl-PL). In my app I'm trying to call:

```
var bingMapsDirectionsTask = new BingMapsDirectionsTask();
var destination = new LabeledMapLocation(dest.Name, dest.LocationItem);
bingMapsDirectionsTask.End = destination;
bingMapsDirectionsTask.Show();
```

When I change device location to other culture, for example en-US the same code works correctly, so I can assume that my code is ok.
I've found some info in Internet about similar problems with other non en cultures. The main workaround based on temporary changing application culture info to en-US:

http://www.apeoholic.se/post/How-to-use-BingMapsDirectionsTask.aspx

http://grenangen.se/node/71

Unfortunately this approach doesn't work with set pl-PL main culture on device. Do you have any suggestions how can I resolve this problem and run Bing maps to show direction to my point?

Comment: What happens when you call the Show method?

Comment: I get message in device UI with information something like that (in polish). "It's not possible connect to Bing maps. Please check your data or WiFi connection". Obviously I have active connection with network.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the same behavior with el-GR (Greek) device language. Your code is obviously OK. This is a bug of BingMapsDirectionsTask. Unfortunately it is present even if  destination is given in GeoLocation form. Currently there seems to be no way of bypassing this bug.